# Let $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}), x f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d x=0 .$ To show that $H f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

> **Question**: Let $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}), x f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d x=0 .$ To show that $H f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}),$ where $H$ is the Hilbert transform.

*Hilbert transform* of a function $f \in \mathscr{S}$  is defined as $$Hf=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi} \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|t|>\varepsilon} \frac{f(x-t)}{t} d t,$$ where $\mathscr{S}$ is Schwarz class.

I have no idea how to start, thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps remind in the post what is the Hilbert transform?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Thanks for reminder, I added the definition.^_^

Comment: Look at the Fourier transform of $f$ and $Hf$.

Comment: @user58955 If $Hf \in L^1(\mathbb R)$, then $\hat{Hf} \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, but I don't know the converse is true or not, so how to do next?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it didn't work. I don't know how to use the assumption that $xf\in L^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Divide $\mathbb R$ into $|x|<\epsilon, |x|>\epsilon$, and use Holder inequality.